# Strange padding inside the UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I've added 2 buttons to my storyboard to show comments and likes num, but the strange padding appears from left and right inside the buttons:

[image: The problem]

My code is:

```
    cell.btnComments.setTitle("199", for: .normal)
    cell.btnComments.setImage(UIImage(named: "3.png"), for: .normal)
    cell.btnComments.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    cell.btnLike.setTitle("19963", for: .normal)
    cell.btnLike.setImage(UIImage(named: "4.png"), for: .normal)
    cell.btnLike.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```

I've tried to make sizeToFit(), but it doesn't work. And there is my Xcode settings:

[image: Xcode]
[image: Xcode]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added:

```
    cell.btnComments.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-23,0,-13)
    cell.btnComments.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-13,0,0)

    cell.btnLike.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-23,0,-13)
    cell.btnLike.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,-13,0,0)
```

and it works!